# The source part of an IRF540N transistor

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, voltage, transistors, dc-dc-converter

So, I have built a DC-DC booster using an IRF540N as my transistor, according to the following schematic diagram.
[image]

It did work and I had a 18V output from a 1.5V battery.

The transistor is connected to an Arduino through the gate to give pulses of 5V to the IRF540N’s gate.

While I was trying it, I found out that it only worked when the source wasn’t connected to the ground, and when I connected it just like the diagram, it didn’t work and only gave me 2V as an output.

This is incredibly weird and it got me very confused. Does anyone has an explanation for that or if I had done something wrong?

Here are the images of the physical circuit:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly, you didn't connect things up the way you thought you did. Show us your physical circuit; this circuit shouldn't do anything at all without the source connected.

Comment: I have added the images. Please take a look and let me know if you find something wrong.

Comment: Did you forget to join the Arduino ground with the lab decks ground?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by the lab decks ground ?

Answer (score 2):

Your inductor value is way too small. It looks like it’s actually 0.1uH (third band is gold, not brown) instead of your intended value.

More here: https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/inductor-color-codes.htm

A good value would be 100uH (brown, black, brown) for 50kHz.